# iPhone Plus: why is UISplitViewController showing both controllers in landscape?

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, landscape, iphone-6-plus

I am using a UISplitViewController with these values:

```
    splitViewController.preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction = 0.4
    splitViewController.minimumPrimaryColumnWidth = 320
    splitViewController.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = 1000
```

- On **iPhone 6** in landscape, the UIViewController shows just 1 controller
- On **iPhone 6 Plus** in landscape, the UIViewController shows both controllers

I can't understand why.

Given the screen sizes of both devices:

```
    iPhone 6:      375 x 667
    iPhone 6 Plus: 414 x 736
```

736 x 0.4 = **294.4**, which is still smaller than **320**

why it's then showing both controllers in landscape for iPhone Plus?

UPDATE:

It looks like `preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction` and `minimumPrimaryColumnWidth` have nothing to do with the threshold width that causes the split. They just define the width of the first controller, in case both controllers are shown.

I am now looking for a way to prevent the split on the iPhone Plus, so that it behaves the same as the iPhone non-Plus.

Comment: did you checked *require full screen*.?

Comment: no, what's that?

Comment: It's because horizontal size class of iPhone 6 Plus in landscape is Regular, not Compact. What mode do you set to `preferredDisplayMode`?

Comment: I didn't set this property, so it defaults to `automatic`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that. **Require Full Screen**. below Status Bar Style.
[image]

Another way:

first check your current mode on different devices.

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController willChangeToDisplayMode:(UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode)displayMode {
  if (displayMode == UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden) {
       NSLog(@"Detail view is visible");
} else if (displayMode == UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible) {
       NSLog(@"both are visible");
  }
}
```

then set your require preferredMode.

Comment: I just verified. I have that checkbox ticked.

Comment: than it should be on full screen. i faced same issue. solved by checking this.

Comment: I had this checkbox already ticked. What does it mean in this case? How it affects UISplitViewController?

Comment: it says in all orientation view should be on full screen.

Comment: how does it affect specifically the UISplitViewController for iPhone 6 Plus?

Comment: There is no impact at all. Apple engineers thinks that its not required to hide, or may be Plus phones will get landscape slide over in later iOS versions.

Comment: it is from documentations.

Comment: try adding the UIRequiresFullScreen key to your Xcode project’s Info.plist file and apply the Boolean value YES.

Comment: It is a useful setting for games that run full screen in landscape only.

Comment: UIRequiresFullScreen is already set to YES in the Info.plist file
So, it doesn't look like this "Requires full screen" explains the situation.

Comment: check your *preferredDisplayMode* than.

Comment: I haven't set a `preferredDisplayMode`, so it defaults to `automatic`.
Is there a way to set the landscape to show just 1 controller on the iPhone Plus, which is the way it already happens on the iPhone?

Comment: you should debugging and check what is current mode on different devices.

Comment: What I am veryfying is that the `splitViewController.displayMode.rawValue` is always 2 (=AllVisible), for both iPhone6 and iPhone6Plus in both portrait and landspace.
I am printing this value in the ViewDidAppear function of the secondary controller.
How can it be possible?

Comment: may be the behavior of UIRequireFullScreen or viewDidLayoutSubviews. needs more debugging just for understanding. and to solve your problem setPreferredMode value to any single controller.